# How can I make screenshots be true pixels?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen-capture

It seems like all my screenshots end up being twice as many pixels as they should even though I run the screen in 1920x1200. If I screenshot this editing box, via <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> it says about 600px across, but the screenshot ends up being about 1200px. See:

[image]

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 5):

This is to be expected, as your Retina MBP has an actual pixel resolution of 3840x2400.

You can downscale your screenshots manually, or use an app like [RetinaCapture](http://www.retinacapture.com/), which takes a full-sized and a downscaled screenshot at the same time.